# Should we ditch [glitch]?

Tags: discussion, tags

Seems we have a tag [glitch](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/glitch).

This seems to me equivalent to having a tag [bug](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/bug). It could apply to issues of various types and with various causes. It seems unlikely that anyone will be especially interested in this tag or consider themselves an expert in it.

Is there any justification for having this tag? Or should we get rid of it (by re-tagging questions that have it, while fixing everything else about these posts that could benefit from editing at the same time)?

Comment: hard to tell IMO a glitch not necessarily has to be a bug. Example: the glitches graphically when installing 16.04 on a Virtualbox VM back in the time, there was no bug in particular and there was an easy fix for that.

Comment: @Videonauth I'm not saying a glitch is necessarily a bug, just that it's an equally generic reference to *a problem of some kind*

Comment: +1 for ditching the glitching instead of "burn", "terminate", "nuke", ...  :-)

Comment: For a moment I thought you were talking about [glitch.com](http://glitch.com).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[glitch](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/glitch) seems to be completely undescriptive as a tag.

We're limited to five tags per post. We should make them useful and descriptive so that people with expertise can find and answer those tagged questions. Nobody can be experienced in "glitch", so I'd say burn the tag.

+1